# Singular function theorem doubt

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have been having problems understanding the Lemma that is stated after this lengthy proof.

$g_n(x)=n[f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)]\:\:\:\text{for}\:\:x\in[a,b]$

$g_n(x)\to g(x)$

$\int_\limits{a}^{b}g(x)\:dx\leqslant\liminf\int_\limits{a}^{b}g_n(x)\:dx=\liminf n\int_\limits{a}^{b}[f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)]\:dx=$
$=**\liminf n\int_\limits{b}^{b+\frac{1}{n}}[f(x)-n\int_\limits{a}^{a+\frac{1}{n}}f(x)]\:dx\leqslant f(a)-f(b)**\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\text{(1)}$

Far ahead on the book it is proved the following:
$\int_\limits{a}^{c}\{F^\prime(x)-f(x)\}dx=0$

$g_n=min[n,f(x)]$

$G_n=\int_\limits{a}^{x}\{f(t)-g_n(t)\}dt$

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_\limits{a}^{x}\{f_n(t)\}dt=f_n(x)\:\:\:\text{a.e}$

$F^\prime(x)=G^\prime_n(x)+\frac{d}{dx}\int_\limits{a}^{x}\{f_n(t)\}dt\geqslant f_n(x)$

$F^\prime(x)\geqslant f(x)\:\:\:\text{a.e}$

**$\int_\limits{a}^{b}F^\prime(x)\:dx\geqslant\int_\limits{a}^{b} f(x)\:dx=F(b)-F(a)**\:\:\:(2)$

By (1) and (2) we have.

$\int_\limits{a}^{b}F^\prime(x)\:dx=F(b)-F(a)=\int_\limits{a}^{b} f(x)\:dx$

A singular function is defined as $F:I\to\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous and monotone, such that $F^\prime(x)=0$.

Lemma: ***A function $F:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is singular if and only if the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $\mu_F$ is non atomic and singular with respect to Lesbegue measure.***

Proof: $\forall, \tau<<\lambda$,(\lambda is Lesbegue measure on the space $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B},\lambda)$ in which $\tau(E)\leqslant\mu(E)$ by (1), $\forall E\:\text{implies}\:\tau=0$.

Apllying Radon-Nykodim
$\mu=\mu_{singular}+\mu_{absolutely continuous}$
As  $\tau(E)\leqslant\mu(E)$ by (1), $\forall E\:\text{implies}\:\tau=0$ implies $\mu=\mu_{singular}$

So we have:

$\mu_F\bot\lambda$

$\tau(E)=\int_E F^\prime\:d\lambda\leqslant\mu_F(E) by (1)$ as $\int_E F^\prime\:d\lambda<<\lambda$. This implies that $F^\prime=0$ and $\mu_F\bot\lambda$.

My question is:

How can we state $\tau(E)\leqslant\mu(E)$ by (1) after proving (2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) The first inequality compromises all kinds of functions including the 
Cantor function that is singular, having a derivative that is zero.On this particular case $F^\prime=0<F$ in the infinitesimal scale. It is important to stress out that despite the fact the tag measure theory is attached the derivative definition is still  $F^\prime=lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.Therefore it is still applicable and understandable that $\tau(E)\leqslant\mu(E)$. Since the function is singular it can no longer be absolutely continuous to Lesbegue which further implies its derivative must be zero.

(2)The second inequality that proves the equality $F^\prime=F$ only holds for functions defined as follows:$F(x)=F(a)+\int_\limits{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ considering the function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lesbegue integrable and $F:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$

Afterwards I found the answer out.